# how to validate adaptive card json using the javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

I am generating an adaptive card json on my own, and I want to validate if that json is well written according to the adaptive card schema. I am reading [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/render-a-card) and from there I have that there is a `parse` function.

I used it this way:

```
import * as AdaptiveCards from 'adaptivecards';

...

try {
  const adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
  adaptiveCard.parse(json);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error', e);
}
```

this approach didn't seem to be working, since the parse accepts everything I pass into it as long as it is a json.

Also I tried this:

```
const v = adaptiveCard.validateProperties();
```

but the response is always the same, no matter if the schema is correct or not.

[image]

I mean, no matter if I have this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.3",
  "body": [
  ]
}
```

or:

```
{
      "schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "version": "1.3",
      "boy": [
        {"catcher": true}
      ]
    }
```

or this:

```
    {
      "schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "version": "1.3",
      "body": [
      {
         "type": "Container"
      }
    ]
  }
```

it always returns the same, even if there are unknown properties, or the Container has no items.

Maybe I am doing this the wrong way.

Any hint on how to validate this?

Comment: The easiest way is to use parse+render wrapped in try/catch. If you can render the card its most likely valid :)

Comment: @TimCadenbach thank you for your comment, post it as a response in order to upvote you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to validate a card is to try to render it. There's a validate function but that doesn't really help and isn't finished.

try this:

```js
var renderedCard = undefined;
try {
  const adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard();
  adaptiveCard.parse(json);
  renderedCard = adaptiveCard.render();
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Error', e);
  return false;
}
```

Any valid card will not throw an exception, that doesn't mean that the card is fully working but at least the json code is valid for sure.